# Multithreading a Windows callback function

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I have a method to set up a window in Windows, written in C. It uses the standard code which looks like this:

```
WNCDCLASS w1 = {0};

w1.lpszClassName = TEXT( "the_window" );
w1.lpfnWndProc = methodIWantOnItsOwnThread;
// snip
```

Now, I have been multithreading with the &ltprocess.h> threads in a method such as:

```
HANDLE h;
h = (HANDLE) _beginthread(methodIWantOnItsOwnThread, 0, 0);
```

How can I multithread like this in the windows callback function, such as with `w1.lpfnWndProc = methodIWantOnItsOwnThread;`?

#### More code.

```
HWND SetupWindow(int device)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    WNDCLASS w1 = {0};

    if (device == 1)
    {
        w1.lpszClassName = TEXT( "window 1" );
        w1.lpfnWndProc   = methodIWantThreaded;
    }
    else
    {
        w1.lpszClassName = TEXT( "window 2" );
        w1.lpfnWndProc   = otherMethodIWantThreaded;
    }
    w1.hInstance     = 0;
    w1.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    w1.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    RegisterClass(&w1);

    hwnd = CreateWindow( w1.lpszClassName, TEXT("The Window"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 520, 650, 520, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL);

    SetTimer(hwnd, 0,30,NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    return hwnd;
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear: do you want your thread to directly handle the window's events? In that case all you need is an event loop.

Comment: I think so.  I'm going to actually have 2 windows (both being called within this same method) and I want both on their own thread.  Should I add more code?

Comment: Why not firstly create thread and in this thread function create window

Comment: Mainly because of my unfamiliarity with this threading syntax.  It seems that to start the thread, you need to pass it the function.  This function, however, needs multiple parameters.  I'm not sure how to lay it out, really..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this backward, and it isn't going to work.

You should be having each **window** create a thread, not each **thread** creating a window. Then you simply create multiple instances of the `WNDCLASS` classname, and each has its own thread that can post and receive messages.

This also gives you a window handle that your main thread's window can use to send and receive messages, allowing you to communicate things to the threads (and vice versa).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?  I will update my question with a fuller method.

Comment: Create a new window using `CreateWindow/CreateWindowEx`, and in response to the `WM_CREATE` message you create the thread using `_beginthread`. The thread registers the thread callback that's part of that window and starts doing what it's supposed to do. It can use the callback to update information on it's parent window, etc. (I can't provide code for this; I haven't used straight C with the WinAPI for ages because there are so many more convenient ways to do things now. I could probably find something in my archives, but you can probably find it faster via SO, Google or MSDN.)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that?

The window proc runs on the thread that created the window handle. Of course, by extension, every thread that creates window handles must have a message loop.

Comment: I'd want to do it because The creation of these windows invokes some methods that refresh what appears on the screen, and I want those on individual threads